# Maximum size of pipe used by CreateProcess

Tags: winapi

I'm currently using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a guide to redirect standard error of a child process launched by `CreateProcess`.

However unlike the example currently I'm waiting until the process finishes (checking `GetExitCodeProcess`), closing the pipe and then reading the error if a non-zero return code comes back.

However I've since read if the pipe fills up the client process will block until the pipe is cleared. The reason I'm not currently reading from the pipe during execution is that the ReadFile call blocks during execution (standard error is only output at the end) so I can't pump the message queue to avoid the GUI from "ghosting" and being marked not responding.

I can't find any reference to how big the pipe is by default (although I can set a size myself), is this something I need to worry about given I'm buffering the output into a string variable for later use anyway? (ie. it would need to fit into the available memory for the process so it has a hard limit there, it's not going to a file like most of the examples have)

Comment: Use another thread to drain the pipe.

Comment: No need to block. You can read from a pipe asynchronously using [`ReadFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468.aspx).